# Remove everything between the first colon and the first tab

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I have lines like this:

```
MSTRG.203.1_294_561:MSTRG.203:nc:376:66.2526979530472:39.7492003264262  2   223 4   no
```

and I want to remove everything between the first colon and the first tab so the result should look like:

```
MSTRG.203.1_294_561 2   223 4   no
```

Is there a way to do this with sed? I tried many different ways but none of them are even close. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Solution 1st:*** If your Input_file is same as shown sample then following may help you in same.

```
awk -F':| ' '{print $1,$9,$12,$13,$16}'  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
MSTRG.203.1_294_561 2 223 4 no
```

***Solution 2nd:*** Or more shorter than previous one.

```
awk '{sub(/:.*/,"",$1)} 1'  Input_file
```

***Solution 3rd:*** With a sed solution too here.

```
sed 's/\([^:]*\)\([^ ]*\)\(.*\)/\1\3/'  Input_file
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: The last script would be much simpler with `sed $'s/:[^\t]*//' Input_file`